# Add a CSS class to an item when Woocommerce cart is empty

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I am trying to hide my cart when it is empty, so I decided to add a CSS class to the cart HTML item when the cart is empty, here is my current code:

```
 function x_woocommerce_navbar_menu_item( $items, $args ) {
      if (WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0 ) {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#header_cart").addClass("zero"); 
                    });
               </script>';
      }
```

I am adding this to my functionts.php file

Am I missing anything?

Comment: add_action( 'wp_footer', 'x_woocommerce_navbar_menu_item' ); is missing if you are adding script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be good if you add the class to body to make the hierarchy in CSS. Use the following code in functions.php :

```
    function tristup_body_classes( $classes )
    {

        global $woocommerce;
        if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
            $classes[]='empty-cart';
        }
        return $classes;
    }
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'tristup_body_classes' );
```

This code will add a class "empty-cart" to body.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it works, However I needed to remove  is_cart() condition

Answer (score 1):

I am posting here a solution which bases on [Tristup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3995972/tristup) answer, as his answer is not 100% correct which observed [Yahya Hussein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5077196/yahya-hussein).

```
add_filter( 'body_class','shoppingCartNotEmpty' );
function shoppingCartNotEmpty( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ? 'shopping-cart-not-empty' 
                                                       : 'shopping-cart-empty';
    return $classes;
}
```

When the shopping cart is empty then the CSS class `shopping-cart-empty` is created, otherwise `shopping-cart-not-empty` is available.

Comment: This works, however, it only works on page reload.  Therefore, if the cart is empty then you add an item, the cart is still hidden until reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in `functions.php` file.

```html
function cart_empty_add_class() {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( empty($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents) ) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#header_cart").addClass("zero"); 
                    });
               </script>';
exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cart_empty_add_class' );
```

Comment: Please elaborate it more or write actual problem which you are getting.