# Add a body class whole site when Woocommerce cart is empty

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to add some description to product list when Woocommerce cart is empty and show/hide by css.

I've tried the following code from [Add a CSS class to an item when Woocommerce cart is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116017/add-a-css-class-to-an-item-when-woocommerce-cart-is-empty)

```
function tristup_body_classes( $classes )
    {

        global $woocommerce;
        if( is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0){
            $classes[]='empty-cart';
        }
        return $classes;
    }
    add_filter( 'body_class', 'tristup_body_classes' );
```

It works fine, however the class is only added on cart page, I'd like it will be added on whole site, how should I do?

Comment: Just remove the if condition wraped with `$classes ` array.

Comment: I removed is_cart() function, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is added in only cart page because you checked the condition whether the page is cart page or not by using **is_cart()**

If you want to implement it in whole site, remove **is_cart()** from the if condition

change your condition to `if( WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0)`